# Horizontal Scrolling Design for Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am learning to code my way through HTML and CSS.
I am right now trying to create a template for a website (as part of my learning process).

I am wanting to create a website that scrolls horizontally only. The website actually needs to have the following visual appearance:

1. A fixed background (to show a clock, a person standing and also a menu (navbar)
2. A horizontal scrolling div that shall appear as a cake shop counter.

I have done the following to scroll horizontally:

```
.scrolling-wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Q1. But the trouble is that I am unable to place it properly. I saw an image ([see here](https://ibb.co/duQoY7)). I want to be able to place the horizontal scrolling as in the image. But I am not able to manage my scrolling wrapper as in the image. How do I do that?

Q2. How do I make someone realize that they need to scroll the website horizontally?

Any inputs will be great from all you guys.

EDIT #1:
I am looking to achieve something like shown in the image
[image: Template Visualization]

All the background elements (Background of wall and floor, Photo of the elephant, Chalk board, Clock, Cart & Menu and the Shop Girl) need to be in their places. While the counter needs to scroll horizontally. As cakes will be added the counter width will increase automatically.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried till now and a working codepen link if possible.

Comment: @GibinEalias I just did that. Please find it here. Its on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/2wteeujj/)

Comment: And for your Q2, you may either make sure the horizontal scroll bar is visible and the vertical one is hidden, which won't be a good UX.
A better way is to set `cursor: ew-resize;` to the scroll area, but it could be bit subtle.

Comment: @GibinEalias could you please check the following link too [View Here](https://html5up.net/ethereal). I really liked this scrolling, placement of the scrolling container (I actually thought to have my cake display scrolling like it, looks great). But the code it out of my comprehension.

Comment: It is pretty much how you have coded in your fiddle. Try adding contents: texts, images and links and you will see it rendering fine. Also note the way they added a padding to have a space on all the sides to emphasis its a horizontal scroll.

Comment: I liked the idea of a Virtual Cake Shop counter. I will be following this post for sure to see how the website design is developed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set `height: 100%;` to the `.scrolling-wrapper` which makes the contents scroll from any part of the page.

Secondly, inorder to make someone realise that they need to scroll the website horizontally, you may either make sure the horizontal scroll bar is visible and the vertical one is hidden, which won't be a good design in terms of UX. A better way is to set `cursor: ew-resize;` to the scroll area, but it could be bit subtle.

Hope this helps.

> Edit

As per the updated question, here is the solution to the issue using `flex` and `absolute` positioning. [PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/yvzWYW)

Hope you will be able to make minor changes to this to perfectly match to the design.

Comment: If you could please [See this](https://html5up.net/ethereal). I am thinking of adding a little something to the bottom right corner to tell people to scroll in horizontal manner. I also am thinking of adding an image that would give a visual effect that there is a flooring and then there are walls and the entire cake display area is a horizontal scrolling thing that will display the cakes inside it.

Comment: I also made the changes suggested by you {in the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/2wteeujj/2/)} and set the position of the scrolling-wrapper to absolute, with bottom and left to 0 (zero) but the scrolling wrapper is still at the top. [Please see](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/2wteeujj/2/)

Comment: To make the contents vertically centered, you may use the flexbox approach as in the given website.
`.scrolling-wrapper{ display: flex;  align-items: center; }`

Comment: Adding the display: flex and align-items: center actually does the trick I am wanting but the issue is [as here](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/2wteeujj/3/) how can I keep the items as in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/genxcoders/2wteeujj/2/) and have the effect that the display: flex gives. I guess it is a simple thing but owing to my limited knowledge I am unable to understand what to do, coz a lot of visual display changes after adding display: flex, like the horizontal scroll bar also disappears. Please could you advise?

Comment: We will open a chat window and discuss tomorrow as now I am away from my machine. Hope thts works for you.

Comment: That would be great. I am from the time zone +5.30 so please let me know a suitable time and also where to open the chat window and how? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @Gibin Ealias, are you around?

Comment: You may join here - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165149/stackoverflow-discussion-on-questions-48750510-gibin-and-aashish

Comment: I have joined the room!